# How do I grep server access logs for unique IPs and a specific page?

Tags: logging, grep, ip-address

I want to grep my server logs to collect all of the unique IP Addresses, and also to see all of the requests for a specific page. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming this is a standard Apache log, and assuming you are on Unix, I usually do

```
awk '{print $1}' access.log|sort -u
```

The awk filters out all IP addresses, the sort then removes duplicates.

To find out all accesses to a URL, I do

```
grep URL access.log
```

Of course, you will have to replace "URL" with the specific one you search for.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use something like [webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/) to process the logs as another option.